# Remove Dash at unwanted position

Tags: tables

[image: enter link description here]

Hello guys,
I am working on table in latex with little bit problem. I want to remove dash line at yellow circle position in attached image.I am using following codes which are given below.. Please try to solve my issue... Thanks...

```
{\begin{tabular}{lcc|cc|c} \toprule

 & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Foreign = 119} && {Local =113} && |  \\ \cmidrule{2-6}

& Mean & SD & Mean & SD  &  p\\ \midrule

Total journal articles and scholarly written works & 16.3898 & 9.34069 & 16.4956 & 8.73327 & .929\\

 Beta &  B2 & B2 & B3 & B4 & B5\\

 Gamma & C2 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
```

Comment: remove the `|`.

Comment: But i need | thisone in the table...

Comment: if you really need a vertical in the header of the last column, make it math: `$|$`.

Comment: @NiamatullahBaloch You're using commands from the package `booktabs`, so you should have read in its documentation that its author strongly advises against using `|` in the table definition.  A better layout would be to allow linebreaks in the first column, more space between "Foreign …", "Local …" and "p" columns, and a gap in the `\cmidrule`.  Use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X@{\qquad} cc% @{\quad} >{\quad}l cc %@{\quad} c} \toprule` as header (you'll also need `\usepackage{tabularx}` and close the table with `\end{tabularx}`) , then replace `cmidrule{2-6}` with …

Comment: @NiamatullahBaloch `\cmidrule{2-3}\cmidrule{5-6}`. There now is a new (empty) column (between "Foreign …"  and "Local …" blocks), so in each line, you must insert `&` for column 4. Don't you think the table looks much nicer now? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `|` symbol. Without font proper encoding, this turns into a `-`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

{
    \begin{tabular}{lcc|cc|c} 
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Foreign = 119} && {Local =113} && \\
        \cmidrule{2-6}
        & Mean & SD & Mean & SD  &  p\\ 
        \midrule
        Total & 16.3898 & 9.34069 & 16.4956 & 8.73327 & .929\\
        Beta &  B2 & B2 & B3 & B4 & B5\\
        Gamma & C2 & C2 & C3 & C4 & C5\\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]